# Is there a way to dynamically use already created variables within a for loop?

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R and I would like to create new variable names and use some others previously created within a for loop.

I found online the way to create the new variables in the loop but I cant make operations with other variables that were created before. I have tried with paste functions and creating the variable wihtin the for loop. Does anybody have an idea of how I could treat this already createdd variables within the loop?

This is how it could be done manually.

```
ACE1_dropc = umxModify(ACE1, update = "c_r1c1", name = "AE")

ACE2_dropc = umxModify(ACE2, update = "c_r1c1", name = "AE")

ACE3_dropc = umxModify(ACE3, update = "c_r1c1", name = "AE")
```

By using the next loop, the variables are created but they all call the same argument `ACE1` in the function `umxMofidy` (`ACE1` is an already created variable of class S4). I want to use different variables (`ACE1`, `ACE2`, `ACE3`) in each iteration but when I try with `paste0("ACE",i)` it doesnt work.

```
for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste("ACE", i, "_dropc", sep = ""), umxModify(ACE1, update = "c_r1c1", name = "AE") )    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a variable via its name using `get()`, although its usually best practice to use lists or other data structure. As an example

```
a1 = 1
z = get(paste0("a",1))
print(z)
1
```

In your loop, you would change the `1` for `i` -> `get(paste0("ACE",i))`

Comment: Not only best practice but also easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is umxModify but I'd definitely move to a `list`. In the example below I am assigning random numbers to the list `l` and then calculate their absolute values. Note that all the elements of the list are named and can be accessed by `l[[paste0("iteration", i)]]`.

```
l <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  l[[paste0("iteration_", i)]] <- rnorm(1)
}

lapply(l, abs)
```